# Dmn table variable rounding using Camunda and SpringBoot (double calculation precision problem)

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda, dmn

I use Camunda and Spring Boot.

I created a dmn-table. But i discoverd a double precision calculation problem.

[image]

I need to calculate result with this dmn table.
We have two variables that come from java: float a, double b.
For example: a= 0.2, b=0.6
And the interval:
[image]

But the precision problem gives me b=0.600000000001~ insted of 0.6 and table gives me another interval
[image]

How can i place rounding inside the dmn table to receive variable result as #.#?

I found a way to round variable, but i doesn't work
[image]

Comment: Can you add a test DMN?

Comment: How are you applying the round function where? On the column header?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. The problem was exactly with the float-values

[image: Camunda]

I just added script in the Expression field